# Kotlin's Iterable and Sequence look exactly same. Why are two types required?

Tags: kotlin, iterable, lazy-sequences

Both of these interfaces define only one method

```
public operator fun iterator(): Iterator<T>
```

Documentation says `Sequence` is meant to be lazy. But isn't `Iterable` lazy too (unless backed by a `Collection`)?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The key difference lies in the semantics and the implementation of the stdlib extension functions for `Iterable<T>` and `Sequence<T>`.

- For `Sequence<T>`, the extension functions perform lazily where possible, similarly to Java Streams *intermediate* operations. For example, [`Sequence<T>.map { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/map.html) returns another `Sequence<R>` and does not actually process the items until a *terminal* operation like `toList` or `fold` is called.

  Consider this code:

  ```
  val seq = sequenceOf(1, 2)
  val seqMapped: Sequence<Int> = seq.map { print("$it "); it * it } // intermediate
  print("before sum ")
  val sum = seqMapped.sum() // terminal
  ```

  It prints:

  ```
  before sum 1 2
  ```

  `Sequence<T>` is intended for lazy usage and efficient pipelining when you want to reduce the work done in *terminal* operations as much  as possible, same to Java Streams. However, laziness introduces some overhead, which is undesirable for common simple transformations of smaller collections and makes them less performant.

  In general, there is no good way to determine when it is needed, so in Kotlin stdlib laziness is made explicit and extracted to the `Sequence<T>` interface to avoid using it on all the `Iterable`s by default.
- For `Iterable<T>`, on contrary, the extension functions with *intermediate* operation semantics work eagerly, process the items right away and return another `Iterable`. For example, [`Iterable<T>.map { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) returns a `List<R>` with the mapping results in it.

  The equivalent code for Iterable:

  ```
  val lst = listOf(1, 2)
  val lstMapped: List<Int> = lst.map { print("$it "); it * it }
  print("before sum ")
  val sum = lstMapped.sum()
  ```

  This prints out:

  ```
  1 2 before sum
  ```

  As said above, `Iterable<T>` is non-lazy by default, and this solution shows itself well: in most cases it has good [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) thus taking advantage of CPU cache, prediction, prefetching etc. so that even multiple copying of a collection still works good enough and performs better in simple cases with small collections.

  If you need more control over the evaluation pipeline, there is an explicit conversion to a lazy sequence with [`Iterable<T>.asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) function.

Comment: Probably a big surprise for `Java` (mostly `Guava`) fans

Comment: @VenkataRaju for functional people they might be surprised at the alternative of lazy by default.

Comment: Lazy by default is usually less performant for smaller and more commonly used collections. A copy can be faster than a lazy eval if taking advantage of CPU cache and so on.  So for common use cases is better to not be lazy.  And unfortunately the common contracts for functions like `map`, `filter` and others don't carry enough information to decide other than from the source collection type, and since most collections are also Iterable, that isn't a good marker for "be lazy" because it is commonly EVERYWHERE.  lazy must be explicit to be safe.

Comment: @JaysonMinard, thanks for your remark, updated the answer.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Excellent answers. The performance inversion comments are an unexpected insight. I recently noticed the default collection operations were making copies, was outraged, and seeked out an alternative: sequences. Is there a good rule of thumb or a very very brief summary writeup on how each approach performs on the average computers of today? If the choice isn't so simple, as you say, a simple guideline would help some of us who are prone to overthinking about those kinds of things.

Comment: if the choice isn't so obvious— I meant.

Comment: @naki this comes under the heading of "cache aware computing and data structures" and it depends on the structure you are using (i.e. array list vs. linked list) and what you are doing with it.  So unless you really become aware of it and care about all of the little details, I would follow this rule of thumb:  don't worry about it unless you see a performance problem, memory problem or you are doing something that is processing millions of things per minute.  Or just test things with a micro-benchmark if you can.  Otherwise more details would never fit into a comment here in SO.

Comment: @naki One example from a recent Apache Spark announcement, they are worrying about this obviously, see "Cache-aware Computation" section at https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html  ... but they are worried about billions of things iterating so they need to go to the full extreme.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Mmkay. I think I will spend some time playing with some benchmarking soon. It'll be a fun and helpful experience to rediscover just what impact the different steps involved in common processing operations have, versus what I imagine. Also, coming from C++, it will be helpful for me to spend some time learning how things actually work on the JVM. A recent forced rush towards productivity has fortunately or unfortunately bypassed my usual desire to master and understand those details.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Unfortunately no "if there are more the 3 operations being chained together, a sequence will always be better"-style hard rules, but I appreciate the "don't worry about it" advice :] Thanks.

Comment: Those rules can't be applied generically @naki, 3 things chained together on a small list rock when in CPU cache, so do 100 working off the same small list!

Comment: Additionally, a common pitfall with lazy evaluation is capturing the context and storing resulting lazy computation in a field along with all the captured locals and whatever they hold. Hence, hard to debug memory leaks.

Answer (score 70):

Completing hotkey's answer:

It is important to notice how Sequence and Iterable iterates throughout your elements:

Sequence example:

```
list.asSequence().filter { field ->
    Log.d("Filter", "filter")
    field.value > 0
}.map {
    Log.d("Map", "Map")
}.forEach {
    Log.d("Each", "Each")
}
```

Log result:

filter - Map - Each; filter - Map - Each

Iterable example:

```
list.filter { field ->
    Log.d("Filter", "filter")
    field.value > 0
}.map {
    Log.d("Map", "Map")
}.forEach {
    Log.d("Each", "Each")
}
```

filter - filter - Map - Map - Each - Each

Comment: That's an excellent example of the difference between the two.

Comment: This is a great example.

Answer (score 2):

> `Iterable` is mapped to the `java.lang.Iterable` interface on the
>   `JVM`, and is implemented by commonly used collections, like List or
>   Set. The collection extension functions on these are evaluated
>   eagerly, which means they all immediately process all elements in
>   their input and return a new collection containing the result.
>
> Here’s a simple example of using the collection functions to get the
>   names of the first five people in a list whose age is at least 21:
>
> ```
> val people: List<Person> = getPeople()
> val allowedEntrance = people
>     .filter { it.age >= 21 }
>     .map { it.name }
>     .take(5)
> ```
>
> Target platform: JVMRunning on kotlin v. 1.3.61 First, the age check
>   is done for every single Person in the list, with the result put in a
>   brand new list. Then, the mapping to their names is done for every
>   Person who remained after the filter operator, ending up in yet
>   another new list (this is now a `List<String>`). Finally, there’s one
>   last new list created to contain the first five elements of the
>   previous list.
>
> In contrast, Sequence is a new concept in Kotlin to represent a lazily
>   evaluated collection of values. The same collection extensions are
>   available for the `Sequence` interface, but these immediately return
>   Sequence instances that represent a processed state of the date, but
>   without actually processing any elements. To start processing, the
>   `Sequence` has to be terminated with a terminal operator, these are
>   basically a request to the Sequence to materialize the data it
>   represents in some concrete form. Examples include `toList`, `toSet`,
>   and `sum`, to mention just a few. When these are called, only the
>   minimum required number of elements will be processed to produce the
>   demanded result.
>
> Transforming an existing collection to a Sequence is pretty
>   straightfoward, you just need to use the `asSequence` extension. As
>   mentioned above, you also need to add a terminal operator, otherwise
>   the Sequence will never do any processing (again, lazy!).
>
> ```
> val people: List<Person> = getPeople()
> val allowedEntrance = people.asSequence()
>     .filter { it.age >= 21 }
>     .map { it.name }
>     .take(5)
>     .toList()
> ```
>
> Target platform: JVMRunning on kotlin v. 1.3.61 In this case, the
>   Person instances in the Sequence are each checked for their age, if
>   they pass, they have their name extracted, and then added to the
>   result list. This is repeated for each person in the original list
>   until there are five people found. At this point, the toList function
>   returns a list, and the rest of the people in the `Sequence` are not
>   processed.
>
> There’s also something extra a Sequence is capable of: it can contain
>   an infinite number of items. With this in perspective, it makes sense
>   that operators work the way they do - an operator on an infinite
>   sequence could never return if it did its work eagerly.
>
> As an example, here’s a sequence that will generate as many powers of
>   2 as required by its terminal operator (ignoring the fact that this
>   would quickly overflow):
>
> ```
> generateSequence(1) { n -> n * 2 }
>     .take(20)
>     .forEach(::println)
> ```

You can find more [here](https://zsmb.co/top-10-kotlin-stack-overflow-questions-1/).

Answer (score 2):

Iterable is good enough for most use cases, the way iteration is performed on them it works very well with caches because of the spatial locality. *But the issue with them is that whole collection must pass through first intermediate operation before it moves to second and so on.*

### In `sequence` each item passes through the full pipeline before the next is handled.

This property can be determental to the performance of your code especially when iterating over large data set. so, if your terminal operation is very likely to terminate early then `sequence` should be preferred choice because you save by not performing unnecessary operations. for example

```
sequence.filter { getFilterPredicate() }   
        .map    { getTransformation()  } 
        .first  { getSelector() }
```

In above case if first item satisfies the `filter` predicate and after `map` transformation meets the selection criteria then `filter`, `map` and `first` are invoked only once.

*In case of iterable whole collection must first be filtered then mapped and then first selection starts*