# Kotlin sequence concatenation

Tags: kotlin

```
val seq1 = sequenceOf(1, 2, 3)
val seq2 = sequenceOf(5, 6, 7)
sequenceOf(seq1, seq2).flatten().forEach { ... }
```

That's how I'm doing sequence concatenation but I'm worrying that it's actually copying elements, whereas all I need is an iterator that uses elements from the iterables (seq1, seq2) I gave it.

Is there such a function?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your code doesn't copy the sequence elements, and `sequenceOf(seq1, seq2).flatten()` actually does what you want: it generates a sequence that takes items first from `seq1` and then, when `seq1` finishes, from `seq2`.

Also, operator `+` is implemented in exactly this way, so you can just use it:

```
(seq1 + seq2).forEach { ... }
```

The source of the operator is as expected:

```
public operator fun <T> Sequence<T>.plus(elements: Sequence<T>): Sequence<T> {
    return sequenceOf(this, elements).flatten()
}
```

You can take a look at the [implementation of `.flatten()` in stdlib](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.0.3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Sequences.kt#L49) that uses [`FlatteningSequence`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.0.3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Sequences.kt#L212), which actually switches over the original sequences' iterators. The implementation can change over time, but `Sequence` is intended to be as lazy as possible, so you can expect it to behave in a similar way.

Example:

```
val a = generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }
val b = sequenceOf(1, 2, 3)

(a + b).take(3).forEach { println(it) }
```

Here, copying the first sequence can never succeed since it's infinite, and iterating over `(a + b)` takes items one by one from `a`.

---

Note, however, that `.flatten()` is implemented in a different way for `Iterable`, and it [**does**](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.0.3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Iterables.kt#L79) copy the elements. Find more about the differences between `Iterable` and `Sequence` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630670/2196460).

Answer (score 6):

Something else you might need to do is create a sequence of sequences:

```
    val xs = sequence {
        yield(1)
        yield(2)
    }

    val twoXs = sequence {
        yieldAll(xs)
        // ... interesting things here ... 
        yieldAll(xs)
    }
```

This doesn't do anything that xs + xs doesn't do, but it gives you a place to do more complex things.