# Kotlin stdlib operatios vs for loops

Tags: kotlin

I wrote the following code:

```
val src = (0 until 1000000).toList()
val dest = ArrayList<Double>(src.size / 2 + 1)    

for (i in src)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0) dest.add(Math.sqrt(i.toDouble()))
}
```

IntellJ (in my case AndroidStudio) is asking me if I want to replace the for loop with operations from stdlib. This results in the following code:

```
val src = (0 until 1000000).toList()
val dest = ArrayList<Double>(src.size / 2 + 1)
src.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
   .mapTo(dest) { Math.sqrt(it.toDouble()) }
```

Now I must say, I like the changed code. I find it easier to write than for loops when I come up with similar situations. However upon reading what `filter` function does, I realized that this is a lot slower code compared to the for loop. `filter` function creates a new list containing only the elements from src that match the predicate. So there is one more list created and one more loop in the stdlib version of the code. Ofc for small lists it might not be important, but in general this does not sound like a good alternative. Especially if one should chain more methods like this, you can get a lot of additional loops that could be avoided by writing a for loop.

My question is what is considered good practice in Kotlin. Should I stick to for loops or am I missing something and it does not work as I think it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance, what you need is `Sequence`. For example, your above code will be

```
val src = (0 until 1000000).toList()
val dest = ArrayList<Double>(src.size / 2 + 1)
src.asSequence()
    .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
    .mapTo(dest) { Math.sqrt(it.toDouble()) }
```

In the above code, `filter` returns another `Sequence`, which represents an intermediate step. Nothing is really created yet, no object or array creation (except a new `Sequence` wrapper). Only when `mapTo`, a terminal operator, is called does the resulting collection is created.

If you have learned java 8 stream, you may found the above explaination somewhat familiar. Actually, `Sequence` is roughly the kotlin equivalent of java 8 Stream. They share similiar purpose and performance characteristic. The only difference is `Sequence` isn't designed to work with `ForkJoinPool`, thus a lot easier to implement.

When there is multiple steps involved or the collection may be large, it's suggested to use `Sequence` instead of plain `.filter {...}.mapTo{...}`. I also suggest you to use the `Sequence` form instead of your imperative form because it's easier to understand. Imperative form may become complex, thus hard to understand, when there are 5 or more steps involved in the data processing. If there is just one step, you don't need a `Sequence`, because it just creates garbage and gives you nothing useful.

Comment: Makes sense, but when I tried it, it was even slower with sequence.

Comment: That is... amazing. Are you sure that your benchmark is correct? I mean, with enough warm up, no JIT removing loops, repeated enough time so no edge case etc.. At least on my end the `Seqence` is faster. (About 25% faster)

Comment: Might be I do not understand the compiler and JVM enough to be benchmarking correctly. I measure time before and after the loop. No warmup - what kind of warmup are we talking about?

my results:
sequence: 110 ms
filter_map: 57 ms
forEach: 48 ms
for loop: 35 ms

filter_map is using non sequence operations.

Comment: Sometimes several loops. even if they copy the whole collection, show good performance because of good locality of reference. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required

Comment: @rozina [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/5818889) explains how to right a correct benchmark on JVM. Though it's designed to educate Java programmers, it works for kotlin, too, since kotlin has JVM backends. Here is a gist of my test code: https://gist.github.com/Glease/900fe08d757631e97e230d90a9b4faa2

Answer (score 3):

You're missing something. :-)

In this particular case, you can use an [`IntProgression`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-progression/):

```
val progression = 0 until 1_000_000 step 2
```

You can then create your desired list of squares in various ways:

```
// may make the list larger than necessary
// its internal array is copied each time the list grows beyond its capacity
// code is very straight forward
progression.map { Math.sqrt(it.toDouble()) }

// will make the list the exact size needed
// no copies are made
// code is more complicated
progression.mapTo(ArrayList(progression.last / 2 + 1)) { Math.sqrt(it.toDouble()) }

// will make the list the exact size needed
// a single intermediate list is made
// code is minimal and makes sense
progression.toList().map { Math.sqrt(it.toDouble()) }
```

Comment: The code was just a made up example. Still a cool trick :) Although, doesn' t creating progression create a new list? Probably with a loop?

Comment: No, a progression generates its elements when iterating it and only stores things like first, last, and step.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to choose whichever coding style you prefer. Kotlin is both object-oriented and functional language, meaning both of your propositions are correct.

Usually, functional constructs favor readability over performance; however, in some cases, procedural code will also be more readable. You should try to stick with one style as much as possible, but don't be afraid to switch some code if you feel like it's better suited to your constraints, either readability, performance, or both.

Answer (score 0):

The converted code does not need the manual creation of the destination list, and can be simplified to:

```
val src = (0 until 1000000).toList()

val dest = src.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
              .map { Math.sqrt(it.toDouble()) }
```

And as mentioned in the excellent answer by @glee8e you can use a sequence to do a lazy evaluation.  The simplified code for using a sequence:

```
val src = (0 until 1000000).toList()

val dest = src.asSequence()                      // change to lazy
              .filter { it % 2 == 0 }
              .map { Math.sqrt(it.toDouble()) }
              .toList()                          // create the final list
```

Note the addition of the `toList()` at the end is to change from a sequence back to a final list which is the one copy made during the processing.  You can omit that step to remain as a sequence.

It is important to highlight the comments by @hotkey saying that you should not always assume that another iteration or a copy of a list causes worse performance than lazy evaluation.  @hotkey says:

> Sometimes several loops. even if they copy the whole collection, show good performance because of good locality of reference. See: [Kotlin's Iterable and Sequence look exactly same. Why are two types required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required)

And excerpted from that link:

> ... in most cases it has good [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) thus taking advantage of CPU cache, prediction, prefetching etc. so that even multiple copying of a collection still works good enough and performs better in simple cases with small collections.

@glee8e says that there are similarities between Kotlin sequences and Java 8 streams, for detailed comparisons see:  [What Java 8 Stream.collect equivalents are available in the standard Kotlin library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254)