# why does operation.map(launch thread).foreach(join()) work in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I've been trying to find an explanation on why this works in kotlin:

```
(1..100).map {
    launch {
        System.out.println("Hello from on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(100)
    }
}.forEach { it.join() }
```

In java this would:

1. start thread 1
2. join thread 1 - and block here, never starting more than 1 thread.

In kotlin this process on multiple threads in parallel.

Why does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` call terminates before `forEach`, thus every single `launch` will be called before the first `join` (inside `forEach`). These *collection operations* don’t work like Java‘s Streams. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630670) for further information.

In Kotlin it’s like this:

- `launch` coroutine 1-100
- `join` coroutine 1-100

Comment: (1..100).asSequence() if you want it to be lazy like java streams. Nvm it's in the linked answer (: