# Stream handling in kotlin

Tags: collections, stream, kotlin

- How will Kotlin work the following code?
- Will a collection of 5000000 integers be created as temporary collection or will the filter feed its result immediately to the `forEach` which means, that only 20 integers will be looked at?
- If not, how would I be able to avoid the intermediate collection?

Code:

```
class Tests {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        var counter = 0
        (1..10_000_000).filter { it % 2 == 1 }.forEach {
            counter++
            if (counter > 10)
                return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note that you can omit parentheses if lambdas are the only argument to a function like `forEach`, I modified your snippet, hope that's fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code sample uses operations on [`Iterable<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterator/index.html), which works eagerly: the [`.filter { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) call will process the whole range and produce a list storing intermediate results.

To alter that, consider using [`Sequence<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html) (e.g. with [`.asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html)) that works lazily, so that the *intermediate* operations such as [`.filter { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/filter.html) produce another lazy sequence and only do the work when items are queried by *terminal* operations such as [`.forEach { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/for-each.html):

```
(1..10000000).asSequence()
    .filter { it % 2 == 1 } 
    .forEach { /* ... */ }
```

See: [Kotlin's Iterable and Sequence look exactly same. Why are two types required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually see the answer to your question pretty quickly by just adding `println(it)` into `filter`:

```
//...
.filter {
   println(it)
   it % 2 == 1
}
//...
```

You'll see **every** number printed. That's because your processing works eagerly as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required).

As already suggested, lazy [**Sequences**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/as-sequence.html) to the rescue: `(1..10_000_000).asSequence()`

Now, the `println(it)` in `filter` will only print the numbers `1..21`, which is definetly preferable in your example.