# Is there any equivalent Kotlin function to Java 8 Stream limit function

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, kotlin, java-stream

I am trying to find the first two elements in a list that meet a condition (filtering), for that purpose I have implemented the following piece of code in kotlin:

```
val arr = 0 until 20

val res = arr.filter { i ->
        println("Filter: $i")
        i % 2 == 0
    }.take(2)
```

Everything was fine until I realized it filters through the whole list, no matter if the two elements have been found.

Making use of Java 8 stream api, it works as expected.

```
val res2 = arr.toList().stream()
     .filter { i ->
          println("Filter: $i")
          i % 2 == 0
     }.limit(2)
```

So my questions is if it can be achieved using only Kotlin functions.

I know I could use a simple for loop but I want to use a functional programming aproach.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kotlin, by default, does these kind of operations **eagerly** whereas *Streams* in Java are **lazy**. You can have the same behaviour in Kotlin if you work with [**sequences**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html), which can easily be generated from `Array`s or `Iterable`s with [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html).

```
arr.asSequence().filter { i ->
    println("Filter: $i")
    i % 2 == 0
}.take(2).toList()

//Filter: 0
//Filter: 1
//Filter: 2
```

Note that the sequence has to be transformed back to a list in the end.

You can read about the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630670/8073652).

Answer (score 7):

By using a sequence, you can get lazy evaluation like a Java 8 stream.  I've rewritten your example with a lazy sequence and explicit types (I haven't changed them, I just declared them for clarity):

```
val arr: IntRange = 0 until 20

val res: List<Int> = arr
    .asSequence()
    .filter { i ->
        println("Filter: $i")
        i % 2 == 0
    }
    .take(2)
    .toList()

// Prints
Filter: 0
Filter: 1
Filter: 2
And res == [0, 2]
```

By turning `arr` into a sequence, performing your `filter` and `take` (which is like Java's `limit`), and turning it back into a List, it will perform lazily.

From [the documentation for Sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html):

> A sequence that returns values through its iterator. The values are evaluated lazily, and the sequence is potentially infinite.