# difference between toList().take(10) and take(10).toList() in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am just trying the new `kotlin` language. I came across sequences which generate infinite list. I generated a sequence and tried printing the first 10 elements. But the below code didnt print anything:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val generatePrimeFrom2 = generateSequence(3){ it + 2 }
    print(generatePrimeFrom2.toList().take(10))
}
```

But when I changed `take(10).toList()` in the `print` statement it work fine. Why is it so ?

This code worked fine for me:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val generatePrimeFrom2 = generateSequence(3){ it + 2 }
    print(generatePrimeFrom2.take(10).toList())
}
```

Comment: "But the below code didnt print anything:" - does it hang and not print anything? Or silently finishes?

Comment: It didnt hang but it was executing continually @SergioTulentsev

Comment: How can you tell the difference, if the program does not produce any output?

Comment: The first snippet of code didn't print anything. But the second code printed the output. Got my solution in below answers @SergioTulentsev 
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the hint -> `generate infinite list`. In the first solution you first want to create a list (wait infinity) then take first 10 elements.

On the second snippet, from infinite list you take only first 10 elements and change it to list

Answer (score 8):

The [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) function generates a sequence that is either infinite or finishes when the lambda passed to it returns `null`. In your case, it is `{ it + 2 }`, which never returns `null`, so the sequence is infinite.

When you call `.toList()` on a sequence, it will try to collect all sequence elements and thus will never stop if the sequence is infinite (unless the index overflows or an out-of-memory error happens), so it does not print anything because it does not finish.

In the second case, on contrary, you limit the number of elements in the sequence with [`.take(10)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/take.html) *before* trying to collect its items. Then the `.toList()` call simply collects the 10 items and finishes.

It may become more clear if you check this Q&A about differences between `Sequence<T>` and `Iterable<T>`: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required)

Comment: Yeah you are right. I think IDE should hint me that `toList().take(10) will be infinite` when I do this on a sequence

Answer (score 1):

`generatePrimeFrom2.toList()` tries to compute/create an *infinite-length* list.
`generatePrimeFrom2.toList().take(10)` then takes the first 10 elements from the *infinite-length* list.
It does not print because it is calculating that *infinite-length* list.

Whereas, `generatePrimeFrom2.take(10)` only tries to compute the first 10 elements.
`generatePrimeFrom2.take(10).toList()` converts the first 10 elements to the list.

You know, `generateSequence(3){ it + 2 }` does not have the *end*. So it has the infinite length.
`Sequence`s do not have actual values, calculated when they are needed, but `List`s have to have actual values.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I think IDE should hint me that `toList().take(10) will be infinite` when I do this on a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

> I came across sequences which generate infinite list.

This is not actually correct. The main point is that a *sequence is not a list*. It is a lazily evaluated construct and only the items you request will actually become "materialized", i.e., their memory allocated on the heap.

That's why it's not interchangeable to write

```
infiniteSeq.toList().take(10)
```

and

```
infiniteSeq.take(10).toList()
```

The former will try to instantiate infinitely many items—and, predictably, fail at it.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I think IDE should hint me that `toList().take(10) will be infinite` when I do this on a sequence

Comment: IDEA 2018 may be introducing some inspections for that (not 100% sure).