# Advantage of adding asSequence() in Array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sequence

Anyone can help me pointing out the difference between the use of asSequence() in the following piece of code.

```
val numbers = 1 .. 50
    val output = numbers.filter{ it < 10 }.map{ Pair("Kotlin", it)}
    output.forEach(::println)
```

Adding `asSequence()`

```
val numbers = 1 .. 50
val output = numbers.asSequence().filter{ it < 10 }.map{ Pair("Kotlin", it)}
output.forEach(::println)
```

Comment: your snippets are identical

Comment: See also: [Kotlin's Iterable and Sequence look exactly same. Why are two types required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The difference is that when you use a `Sequence` it will only run the functions if you iterate over the elements. So for example this:

```
val numbers = 1 .. 50
val output = numbers.asSequence().filter{
    println("Filtering $it")
    it < 10
}.map{
    println("Mapping $it")
    Pair("Kotlin", it)
}
```

will print nothing, because you did not iterate over `output`.

Checking the docs helps:

```
/**
 * Creates a [Sequence] instance that wraps the original collection
 * returning its elements when being iterated.
 */
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.asSequence(): Sequence<T> {
    return Sequence { this.iterator() }
}
```

Using `Sequence`s is useful because if you just call `map` on a `Collection` the result will be converted to a `List` and with a `Sequence` you can avoid these conversion steps. Think about `Sequence`s like `Stream`s in the Java Stream API (with the difference that Kotlin's solution does not support parallel execution).