# Get top N elements in SortedMap?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any correct way to get top N elements from SortedMap? My variant is:

```
val sortedMap = map.filterValues { it in sortedValues }.toSortedMap()
if (sortedMap.size <= 20) {
    return sortedMap
}
var result = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
for ((key, value) in sortedMap) {
    result[key] = value
    if (result.size == 20) {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: use `headMap` with the 20th key as argument?

Answer (score 3):

`headMap` is also a good solution for getting a portion of this map, for example

```
      return when {
        sortedMap.size >= 20 -> {
            sortedMap.headMap(sortedMap.keys.elementAt(20))
        }
        else -> {
            sortedMap
        }
    }
```

more from the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/SortedMap)

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
val first20AsList: List<Map.Entry<String, Int>> = sortedMap.asIterable().take(20)
val first20AsMap: Map<String, Int> = first20AsList.associate { it.toPair() }
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

In my opinion the best way is to use `asSequence()` because it is evaluated lazily:

```kotlin
return sortedMap.asSequence().take(20).map{ it.toPair() }.toMap()
```

#### Information on Lazy evaluation

In general it is often favorable to use lazy variants of iterable containers, because it means that in many cases not the whole datastructure needs to be evaluated but just the portion of data that is required.

In your case that would be the first N in the `SortedMap`. If it really happens to result in a performance advantage is questionable, but at least it is possible.

Some Information from stack-overflow and kotlin on lazy sequences:

- [Kotlin's Iterable and Sequence look exactly same. Why are two types required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required/35630670)
- [Sequences @ kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html)

#### Old Answer:

This answer was improved in some details thanks to the comment by @IR42. Before I used the `spread` operator for conversion to a sorted-map again (via `sortedMapOf`), and `map { it.key to it.value }` instead of `{ it.toPair() }`:

```kotlin
return sortedMapOf(
    *sortedMap.asSequence().take(20)
         .map{ it.key to it.value }
         .toList().toTypedArray())
```

Comment: `.take(20).map { it.toPair() }.toMap()`

Comment: thanks, i will edit it accordingly, Ok so it will automagically create a sortedMap again?

Comment: no, but according to the code in the question, it doesn't matter which "map" is under the hood, most likely the return type of the function is `Map<String, Int>`. You also can use `.toMap(sortedMapOf())` if you need `SortedMap`

Comment: you are right, the OP just used the sortedMap to get the first 20 elements and returns a standard mutable-map afterwards. Thanks for pointing that out as well. :D Actually I was just thinking it would be great to have some notion of *sharing* points/reputation if an answer was much improved by e.g. a comment or anything.

Answer (score 0):

What u could try is `flatMap{}` from where u can get list of those items and then use `take()` function on that list to determine amount of it. Example:

```kotlin
val list = mapOf<Int, Boolean>(
    1 to true,
    2 to false,
    3 to true
).toSortedMap().flatMap {
    listOf(it)
}.take(2) 
println(list[1].key) // <-- 2
```

`take(n)`

> Returns a list containing first n elements.