# Kotlin list, filter by boolean in object

Tags: kotlin, filter

I have a list of objects. There is a boolean field `isOpen` in the object, and I only want the objects that are open.

for example:

```
val filteredList = myObjectList.asSequence()
    .filter { document ->
        document.isOpen
    }
```

but this doesn't work.

What do I have to do so that the filter queries each object in the list and only takes the one with the boolean true value?

Thanks

Comment: This is correct, except that you named the variable "list" when it's a sequence. To convert a Sequence to a List, you have to call `toList()` on the result. There's no point in using `asSequence()` when you are not chaining multiple iterations of the results. Note that `filter` has no effect on the original `myObjectList()`. If `myObjectList` is mutable and you want to filter it in place, use `retainAll` instead of `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you have is a list and you want to filter it, converting to a sequence is overkill. You can just do:

```
val filteredList = myObjectList.filter { it.isOpen }
```

Example:

```
data class Document(val id: Int, val isOpen: Boolean)

fun main() {
    val myObjectList = listOf(
        Document(1, true),
        Document(2, false),
        Document(3, false),
        Document(4, true),
        Document(5, true),
    )

    val filteredList = myObjectList.filter { it.isOpen }
    println(filteredList)
}
```

Output:

```
[Document(id=1, isOpen=true), Document(id=4, isOpen=true), Document(id=5, isOpen=true)]
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Actually the issue was with some logic afterwards, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think this post answers your question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required#:~:text=In%20contrast%2C%20Sequence%20is%20a%20new%20concept%20in,the%20date%2C%20but%20without%20actually%20processing%20any%20elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629159/kotlins-iterable-and-sequence-look-exactly-same-why-are-two-types-required#:%7E:text=In%20contrast%2C%20Sequence%20is%20a%20new%20concept%20in,the%20date%2C%20but%20without%20actually%20processing%20any%20elements).

So, sequence is lazy, if you want filtering you have to collect results, e.g.

```kotlin
val filteredList = myObjectList.asSequence()
    .filter { document ->
        document.isOpen
    }.toList()
```

or you can use Iterable instead of Sequence.